# Python - for loop with if

Tags: python-3.x, loops

could you please help me understand what's wrong in the script below and how to correct it?
I am just trying to add a column iterating over the file. The new column should say 'F', if the percentage of females is higher than the percentage of males.
Thank you very much!

```py
babies_df = pd.read_csv('datasets/babynames_nysiis.csv', delimiter=';')

gender=[]
for idx in range(len(babies_df)):
    if babies_df['perc_female'>'perc_male']:
        gender.append('F')
    else:
        gender.append('M')

babies_df['gender'] = gender
```

Comment: I think you should use `babies_df['perc_female'] > babies_df['perc_male']`

Comment: thanks PSKP, tried that already but it does not work :(

Comment: In `if` statement you mistakenly comparing inside `[ ]` which is wrong. you should complete first column. If still error persist please add error also.

Comment: Sure, thanks for helping, this is the code:

babies_df = pd.read_csv('datasets/babynames_nysiis.csv', delimiter=';')

gender=[]
for idx in range(len(babies_df)):
if babies_df['perc_female’]> babies_df[’perc_male']:
    gender.append('F')
else:
    gender.append('M')

babies_df['gender'] = gender

Comment: and this is the error:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-195-cbb09ab25ce5> in <module>()
      4 gender=[]
      5 for idx in range(len(babies_df)):
----> 6     if babies_df['perc_female']>babies_df['perc_male']:
      7         idx.append('F')
      8     else:

Comment: /var/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1574         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1575                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1576                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1577 
   1578     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: I added answer which will solve your question. If you got your answer please accept solution as answer to question else comment what's problem with solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `babies_df['perc_female'>'perc_male']` is not correct syntax.

You could try pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for your solution.

```py
babies_df = pd.read_csv('datasets/babynames_nysiis.csv', delimiter=';')

babies_df['gender'] = babies_df.apply(
    lambda x: 'F' if x['perc_female'] > x['perc_male'] else 'M', 
    axis=1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is, you are not iterating `row by row` and also you are comparing columns directly which is not possible.

```py
babies_df = pd.read_csv('datasets/babynames_nysiis.csv', delimiter=';')

for index, row in babies_df.iterrows():
    if row["perc_female"] > row["perc_male"]:
        gender.append("F")
    else:
        gender.append("M")

babies_df["gender"] = gender
```